# Best practise to escape XML characters?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, escaping, dom4j

I've got html datas that i'm converting into a Dom4J document.

I've met an error:

```
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : Reference is not allowed in prolog. Nested exception: Reference is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.dom4j.DocumentHelper.parseText(DocumentHelper.java:278)
    at MonTest.main(MonTest.java:21)
Nested exception: 
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Reference is not allowed in prolog.
```

It was a character "&" that i needed to escape into & amp; in order to build the document.

In XML, it seems that we need to escape 5 characters: (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos)

Nevertheless, how can i escape it, without escaping it into the "nodes" elements:

```
<div id="test" class='toto'>A&A<A"A</div>
```

should give:

```
<div id="test" class='toto'>A&amp;A&lt;A&quot;A</div>
```

and not

```
&lt;div id=&quot;test&quot; class=&apos;toto&apos;&gt;A&amp;A&lt;A&quot;A&lt;/div&gt;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape strings before adding to XML document. Use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml method from Apache Commons Lang. Use some library to build XML e.g. http://code.google.com/p/joox/.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at using a lenient HTML XMLReader instead of the default XMLReader implementation. Something like [tag soup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).